# Why does Jest fail without the flag --runInBand?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

When I run tests without the flag `--runInBand` or with `maxWorkers` greater than 1 they fail. However, if I provide the flag or change `maxWorkers`, everything passes.

[CodeSanbdox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-js-8ni24b)

**Failure scenario:**
Steps to reproduce:

1. `npx jest --clearCache`
2. `npx jest`

The result of that should be as follows:
[image]

**Success scenario:**
Steps to reproduce:

1. `npx jest --clearCache`
2. `npx jest --runInBand`

The result of that should be as follows:
[image]

I am expecting all tests to pass regardless of the flag/`maxWorkers`.

Answer (score 2):

In the Jest documenatation runInBand is explained as

```
Run all tests serially in the current process, rather than creating a worker pool of child processes that run tests. This can be useful for debugging
```

When your tests run in parallel they might be effected by each other.

Comment: Yes, but did you see the tests provided by me? How can they be affected by each other? I mean they are straightforward and should be independent.